# How can I pass a callable object to another function/subroutine without calling/invoking it?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm using VBA 7.1 in MS Office 2013. I'm trying to interact with a function in JavaScript (or an interface of it created using as close as possible in shortened code `CreateObject("HtmlFile").ParentWindow.close` - similar to `window.close` in JavaScript). The problem is, I'm trying to pass it to another function, but it keeps calling the actual `window.close` function in JavaScript *as I pass it*. This is where it gets weird: it doesn't get invoked in a few specific built-in functions.

```
CStr(obj) ' Invokes the interface; window close dialog appears
VarType(obj) ' Invokes the interface; window close dialog appears
IsEmpty(obj) ' Invokes the interface; window close dialog appears
TypeName(obj) ' Doesn't invoke the interface; returns "Object"
IsObject(obj) ' Doesn't invoke the interface; returns True
```

Is there a way to pass it around *without* invoking it?

**EDIT:** You can replicate the setup using this:

```
With CreateObject("HtmlFile")
    .ParentWindow.ExecScript "obj = window.close"
    Set obj = .ParentWindow.obj
End With
```

Comment: Function/method pointers aren't really a thing in VBA.  You could try passing it as two separate parameters: the object itself and the method name as a string, then using `CallByName` on the callee side (assuming you want to invoke the method there).

Comment: Please show the entire code, where you are trying to pass it to another function. What is the `obj` variable?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question is you pass the name of the object.

Objects are CODE. There is an object factory that makes your object.

The data structures for an object is 4x32 bit integers (Longs in VB talk). One is the reference count (and if 0 the object terminates), one is the address of the VTable (the address of each property get/set and method calls), two are reserved and are unused and always will be.

Due to the magic of COM your object appears as a data structure and a loaded function library in your program (even if it's an executable rather than a dll).

To pass objects that don't yet exist pass the name. JScript/VBScript can write code at runtime. In VBScript see `execute`, `executeglobal`, and `eval`. All take a string of VBScript code that becomes part of your program in various ways.